# Jenkins does not fill in the sender for emailed results. It gives a variable name instead ${NotifyByMail.Sender}

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins does not fill in the sender for emailed results. It gives a variable name instead ${NotifyByMail.Sender}

the results notification emails from all our Jenkins projects do not have the sender name filled in. It just has ${NotifyByMail.Sender} .

This was working a couple of weeks ago, then it stopped substituting the sender name. I looked at the Jenkins config, but could not find anything that looked like a culprit.

Also, at the same time, the results in the email body became blank (empty)